# AKS and Azure AD Multi-Tenant access

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I struggle with an architecture question. I need to have multiple AD tenants for a desktop solution but I also need the Desktop app to access services in different AKS namespaces.

Every time I create an AD tenant it seems like it has its own resources and would need its own AKS Cluster.

Is there a concept of access AKS services in a different tenant?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy AKS as a multitenant Kubernetes cluster and is shared by multiple users and workloads that are commonly referred to as "tenants." Cluster multitenancy is an alternative to managing many single-tenant dedicated clusters. The operators of a multitenant Kubernetes cluster must isolate tenants from each other, to minimize the damage that a compromised or malicious tenant can do to the cluster and to other tenants.

When you plan to build a multitenant Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster, you should consider the layers of resource isolation that are provided by Kubernetes: cluster, namespace, node, pod, and container. You should also consider the security implications of sharing different types of resources among multiple tenants. For example, scheduling pods from different tenants on the same node could reduce the number of machines needed in the cluster. On the other hand, you might need to prevent certain workloads from being colocated. Although Kubernetes cannot guarantee perfectly secure isolation between tenants, it does offer features that may be sufficient for specific use cases. As a best practice, you should separate each tenant and its Kubernetes resources into their own namespaces. You can then use [Kubernetes RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)and [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to enforce tenant isolation

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-cluster-isolation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/aks-agic/aks-agic

Comment: Hi JayakrishnaGunnam-MT, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the idea is to have Active-Directory Tenants and these need to access the same services in one AKS Cluster. How does this work?